# Ender 3 extruder skips

Tags: creality-ender-3

I'm printing a 3D flower model using an old Ender 3 printer.

At first the printer was printing so well but suddenly, when printing something, the extruder starts to skip and make noises and stops loading filament to the nozzle and not printing at all.

After disassembling the PTF tube, it turns out that it was clogged so I decided to replace it with a Capricorn Bowden tube and after trying to print with the new upgrade the extruder is still skipping or clicking and making a noise and the nozzle is almost extruding filament.

I have uploaded a video that describes the issue: [extruder skipping ender 3](https://youtu.be/7oRFU4B8GtM?si=_5aL6C9CKSkxOlaB)

BTW I'm using very cheap PLA filament.

Comment: Have you tried changing the nozzle? It could be that it is clogged as well.